# How to solve this differential equation? $y=\left(y'\right)^2+4\left(y'\right)^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, hey.
I've tried to substitute $y'=p$ and solve it somehow, but it didn't result in any acceptable equation.
Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y'=p\Rightarrow y=p^2+4p^3\Rightarrow p=y'=(2p+12p^2)p'\Rightarrow p=0$ or $p'=\frac{1}{2+12p}\Rightarrow p=0$ or $2p+6p^2=x+C\Rightarrow p=0$ or $p=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{6}x+C}-\frac{1}{6}\Rightarrow y=C$ or $y=\pm\frac{\sqrt{6}}{9}(x+C)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{1}{6}x+C_1$.